# Получить данные из определённого листа Google Sheets

Tags: python, google-spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

Таков код:

```py
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
    self.CREDENTIALS_FILE,
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
     'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'])
httpAuth = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
service = apiclient.discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', http=httpAuth)

request = service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, ranges=ranges,
                                             includeGridData=include_grid_data)
```

По умолчанию выводится лист 1 (Maket 1). Как получить доступ к другим листам, если spreadsheetId листов одинаковый, а различаются они лишь по gid в ссылке? Для первого листа соответственно значение 0. У других листов gid состоит из 9-10-значного числа

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/**spreadsheet_id**/edit#gid=**0**

Каким образом можно получить значения с другого листа?

[image: Доступные листы в Google таблице]

**Решение:**

```py
request = service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, ranges=['Maket 2!C4'],
                                             includeGridData=include_grid_data)
```

Просто параметр ranges надо указать в формате **[имя листа!B2:D5]**

Источник - https://habr.com/ru/post/483302/

Answer (score 1):

[gspread](https://github.com/burnash/gspread)    [gspread user-guide](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html)

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

gscope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
gcredentials = 'test.json'
gdocument = 'test'  # название таблицы


credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(gcredentials, gscope)
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
wks = gc.open(gdocument).worksheet('Тест')  # название листа

val = wks.acell('B1').value
```

Comment: gspread не могу использовать, потому что в таблице нужна ориентация по цвету ячейки. Где-то читал, что определить цвет ячейки в gspread нельзя, поэтому использую google-api-python-client и oauth2client. Да и проблему свою я уже решил, но всё равно спасибо

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41999817/12785139, https://stackoverflow.com/a/37939722/12785139 ?